# Upload csv file to Google Drive from R

Tags: r, api, google-drive-api, httr

I have a shared folder in google drive. I'll use this link as an example:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1on07liV24xKCVpcWkOJEu6Ci8Lmcl9hi

I have a script in r like below:

```
head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

##Work Directory?
write_csv(mtcars, 'mtcars_dataset.csv')
```

How do I set my work directory to be this shared folder?

I attempted to use the `googledrive` package but I could only find a way to access files rather than folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your working directory manually by

```
setwd("C:/Users/*user name*/Google Drive/*shared folder*")
```

Comment: Is the username just your email?

Comment: No, the user name for your PC. 
Just copy the path where you want to save your file from your explorer's address bar and set it as working directory using `setwd("_paste path_")`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to download Google Drive File Stream. This worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [googledrive package](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/index.html), there is the function `drive_upload`. You can take a look on [the documentation](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/reference/drive_upload.html).

Basically you need to specify your file, the path to upload and a name for the file.

I hope it's clear!